# Model.findOneAndDelete Mongoose CRUD

Tags: javascript, mongoose, crud

`PostModel.findOneAndDelete( { _id: postId, },  ).then((doc) => { if(!doc) { return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Article not found',  error: err }); } res.json({ success: true, }) }).catch((err) => { if(err) { return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to delete article',  error: err }); } })`

I used a promise, and everything seems to work, but there is some kind of error at the stage with catch, which I don’t understand